# Where's the allocation coming from?

Tags: go

I'm writing an OpenType font (OTF) decoder in Go, and I have the following code:

```
// Errors: The different errors that can occur while decoding Open Type font data.
var (
    errUnexpectedEOF   = errors.New("otf: unexpected EOF")
    errUnsupportedSFNT = errors.New("otf: unsupported SFNT version")
)

// Helpers: Re-usable buffers to optimize the amount of allocations.
var (
    uint32Buff = make([]byte, 4)
)

// Decode reads and decode an Open Type front from rdr.
func Decode(rdr io.Reader) (fonts.Font, error) {
    // Read the SFNT version.
    if _, err := readSfntVersion(rdr); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return nil, nil
}

// PRIVATE: Read the SFNT version of the font.
func readSfntVersion(rdr io.Reader) (uint32, error) {
    if value, err := readUint32(rdr); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    } else if value != 0x00010000 && value != 0x4F54544F {
        return 0, errUnsupportedSFNT
    } else {
        return value, nil
    }
}

// PRIVATE: Read the next 4 bytes as an uint32 (using Big Endian) from rdr.
func readUint32(rdr io.Reader) (uint32, error) {
    if b, err := readBytes(rdr, 4, make([]byte, 4)); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    } else {
        return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b), nil
    }
}

// PRIVATE: Read exactely amount bytes from rdr into buff.
func readBytes(rdr io.Reader, amount int, buff []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if n, err := io.ReadFull(rdr, buff); err != nil || n < amount {
        return buff, errUnexpectedEOF
    } else {
        return buff, nil
    }
}
```

I have the following simple benchmark.

```
// PRIVATE: The data to verify (and measure the performance) of the public API of the `otf` package.
var (
    // PRIVATE: A slice which contains NO data.
    fontWithoutSfntVersion []byte = []byte{
        // NOTE: Intentionally left blank.
    }
)

// PRIVATE: The scenario's to verify (and measure the performance) of the `otf.Decode` function.
var tbDecodeScenarios = [...]struct {
    name        string
    otfData     []byte
    expectedErr error
}{
    {
        name:        "An OTF font without an SFNT version.",
        otfData:     fontWithoutSfntVersion,
        expectedErr: errors.New("otf: unexpected EOF"),
    },
}

// PRIVATE: Holds the result of the `otf.Decode` benchmark function.
//          These variables are required to avoid compiler optimizations.
var (
    benchmarkDecodeFont fonts.Font
    benchmarkDecodeErr  error
)

// BENCHMARK: Measure the performance of the Kind.String function.
func BenchmarkDecode(b *testing.B) {
    // EXECUTION.
    for _, scenario := range tbDecodeScenarios {
        scenario := scenario // NOTE: Ensure that the b.Run function has the correct value when it's being executed.

        b.Run(scenario.name, func(b *testing.B) {
            // RUN.
            for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                // ARRANGE.
                otfRdr := bytes.NewReader(scenario.otfData)

                // ACT.
                benchmarkDecodeFont, benchmarkDecodeErr = otf.Decode(otfRdr)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The output shows that there are 2 allocations:

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf
cpu: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor
BenchmarkDecode/An_OTF_font_without_an_SFNT_version.-16                 12962000               105.3 ns/op            52 B/op          2 allocs/op
PASS
ok      github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf 1.827s
```

I'm wondering where this 2nd allocation is coming from.
I can reduce the amount of allocations to 1 if I change the implementation of the `readUint32` function to:

```
// Helpers: Re-usable buffers to optimize the amount of allocations.
var (
    uint32Buff = make([]byte, 4)
)

// PRIVATE: Read the next 4 bytes as an uint32 (using Big Endian) from rdr.
func readUint32(rdr io.Reader) (uint32, error) {
    if b, err := readBytes(rdr, 4, uint32Buff); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    } else {
        return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b), nil
    }
}
```

Which I don't understand since this function is only called once.
Who can shine a light upon this this behaviour?

*Edit:*

When running the benchmark (and creating a profile), here's the output of `pprof top10`.

```
Type: alloc_space
Time: Mar 30, 2022 at 10:58pm (CEST)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top10
Showing nodes accounting for 687.53MB, 99.28% of 692.53MB total
Dropped 20 nodes (cum <= 3.46MB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  629.53MB 90.90% 90.90%   629.53MB 90.90%  bytes.NewReader (inline)
      58MB  8.38% 99.28%       58MB  8.38%  github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf.readUint32
         0     0% 99.28%       58MB  8.38%  github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf.Decode
         0     0% 99.28%       58MB  8.38%  github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf.readSfntVersion
         0     0% 99.28%   687.53MB 99.28%  github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf_test.BenchmarkDecode.func1
         0     0% 99.28%   687.53MB 99.28%  testing.(*B).launch
         0     0% 99.28%   687.53MB 99.28%  testing.(*B).runN
(pprof)
```

Zooming in on the `readUint32` function shows:

```
(pprof) list readUint32
Total: 692.53MB
ROUTINE ======================== github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf.readUint32 in D:\Development\github.com\kdeconinck\otf-decode\app\internal\pkg\fonts\otf\otf.go
      58MB       58MB (flat, cum)  8.38% of Total
         .          .     81:   }
         .          .     82:}
         .          .     83:
         .          .     84:// PRIVATE: Read the next 4 bytes as an uint32 (using Big Endian) from rdr.
         .          .     85:func readUint32(rdr io.Reader) (uint32, error) {
      58MB       58MB     86:   if b, err := readBytes(rdr, 4, make([]byte, 4)); err != nil {
         .          .     87:           return 0, err
         .          .     88:   } else {
         .          .     89:           return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b), nil
         .          .     90:   }
         .          .     91:}
```

When using a re-usable buffer, the top10 command in pprof doesn't even show the `readUint32` function.

Comment: can you try to profile the code ? https://go.dev/blog/pprof

Comment: Sure, I added benchmark output. But I still don't get it.

Comment: you are looking for -alloc_objects sample kind. Though, i hardly find a doc about this which is not a blog.

Comment: Even with the `-alloc_objects` sample kind, I can't find out where the 2nd allocation is coming from.

Comment: try `list NewReader`

Comment: Once you found it, try https://pkg.go.dev/testing#B.ResetTimer

Comment: Here you lost me a bit. Where should I place the reset timer? My benchmark just executes a single function. And still I don't understand why I have 2 allocations vs 1 (when using a package-defined buffer), the function is only called once.

Comment: this line `otfRdr := bytes.NewReader(scenario.otfData)` is accounted or an allocation in your report. As it is calld n times, it reports that many much allocations. Though, i should not have mentionned resettimer in your case, i have missread your code (though it is useful). By moving the buffer allocation before the loop, and reseting it within the loop you get ride of that allocation. https://go.dev/play/p/F5HFHuNhY8S

Answer (score 0):

The benchmarking functions counts all allocations inside the loop

```
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            // ARRANGE.
            otfRdr := bytes.NewReader(scenario.otfData)

            // ACT.
            benchmarkDecodeFont, benchmarkDecodeErr = otf.Decode(otfRdr)
        }
```

Your pprof output gives as clear hint where the allocations are:

```
  629.53MB 90.90% 90.90%   629.53MB 90.90%  bytes.NewReader (inline)
      58MB  8.38% 99.28%       58MB  8.38%  github.com/kdeconinck/otf-decode/internal/pkg/fonts/otf.readUint32
```

This shows that one of the two allocations is inside the `bytes.NewReader()` call inside the loop.  The second allocation is the `make([]byte, 4)` in the first line of the `readUint32()` function (called via `Decode` and `readSfntVersion`).